# How to handle autoreleased objects in iOS with ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, autorelease

I am creating an iPhone application with ARC enabled, in this I am having a situation.

In each page of the application, a web service call is happening. And in this method I am removing all the objects from the arrays before adding new value from the server. All is working fine, but sometimes app is crashing at `[self.myArray removeAllObjects]`.

I have set @property for myArray `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray myArray;`

What I am thinking is, as I am using ARC, the object, `myArray`, is got released at some point and I try to remove all the objects from the same array. That causing the crash, I am not sure but I don't see any other reason for this.

So, I was thinking about to check, whether the array is valid before I remove the objects in it. I wrote a sample code to check the different scenarios. Here it is:

```
NSMutableArray *testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];

if (testArray) {
    NSLog(@"i am alive");
}

[testArray release];

if (testArray) { //here how to check whether this array is valid or not?
    NSLog(@"i am alive: %@", testArray);
}else{
    NSLog(@"I am dead");
    testArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", nil];
}

[testArray release];
[testArray removeAllObjects];
```

I know it will cause crashes, but it is just for checking. Here, how can I check whether the array is valid? Is this is a right approach or something else?

Please guide me.
Thanks.

**Actual Code:**

```
- (void)getFriendsList{

    BOOL netIsAvailable = [self connected];

    if (netIsAvailable) {
        @try {
            NSString *accessToken = [self getAccessToken];
            NSString *tokenEncoded = [accessToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];
            NSString *finalUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@FriendsnSongs/%@",CommonWebServiceUrl,tokenEncoded];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
            NSURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSData *currentResult = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
//            NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:currentResult encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            if (currentResult != nil) {
                NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                      JSONObjectWithData:currentResult
                                      options:kNilOptions
                                      error:&error];
                NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                int statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

                NSMutableArray *match = [json valueForKey:@"FriendsnSongsResult"];
                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    if (self.userGuidArray) {
                        [self.albumNameArray removeAllObjects];  //here got crash
                        [self.artistNameArray removeAllObjects];
                        [self.deviceNameArray removeAllObjects]; //here also got crash once
                        [self.nickNameArray removeAllObjects];
                        [self.userProfileImageArray removeAllObjects];
                        [self.songTitleArray removeAllObjects];
                        [self.songStatusArray removeAllObjects];
                        [self.userGuidArray removeAllObjects];
                    }

                    for(NSArray *player in match) {
                        [self.albumNameArray addObject:[(NSArray *)player valueForKey:@"AlbumName"]];
                        [self.artistNameArray addObject:[(NSArray *)player valueForKey:@"Artist"]];
                        [self.nickNameArray addObject:[(NSArray *)player valueForKey:@"NickName"]];
                        [self.userProfileImageArray addObject:[(NSArray *)player valueForKey:@"ProfileImage"]];
                        [self.songStatusArray addObject:[(NSArray *)player valueForKey:@"Status"]];
                        [self.songTitleArray addObject:[(NSArray *)player valueForKey:@"Title"]];
                        [self.userGuidArray addObject:[(NSArray *)player valueForKey:@"UserGuid"]];
                        [self.deviceNameArray addObject:[(NSArray *)player valueForKey:@"DeviceName"]];
                    }
                    //Start timer for updating the friends list
                    if (timerActivated)
                        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(backgroundFriendsListUpdate) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                    //Update table if the table not in search mode
                    if (!isSearching)
                        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTable) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
                }
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Exception: %@",exception.name);
        }
    }
    [DejalActivityView removeView];
}
```

And the important point is, in this class a background thread is running in every 30 seconds. It will call this same method for refreshing the table.

Comment: wt is error and why u use testArray release]; even u using ARC ????

Comment: Once released you can't test it as theres nothing there anymore. I'd be more inclined to get to the root of the problem rather than dance around it.

Comment: @iPatel in this sample code I am not using ARC, i wrote this only to check whether an object is valid or not even after release.

Comment: @Jonathan I am not sure it would be issue, but I am asking does it, the situation that I mentioned, cause the issue?

Comment: If it only happens some of the time most likely you have two threads accessing the same instance. What's the exact crash you get?

Comment: Performing any operation on an object that has been released will cause a crash, if thats what you are asking?

Comment: I'm almost sure that your problem is not ARC-related. Please show the actual code and the error message you get.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I have added exception break points, so the error happened at [self.myArray removeAllObjects]; And also I used try and catch, so in the exception part the exception was NSRangeException.

Comment: @Jonathan Yes, exactly, I wonder that is happening here.

Comment: I have added the actual code, please check.

Comment: @Mithuzz `NSRangeException` probably means you are trying to access some object in the array at index thats beyond bounds of your array. I bet you are using a UITableview to present your data, and since you update its data source from a background thread, `NSRangeException` is likely.

Comment: @Adam I understand what you said, but can you suggest any possible modifications in the above code? And also to avoid this issue, can i use a temporary arrays for getting the data from the sever and instead of removing all the previous contents just replace it with the latest contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested in the comments, using temporary array is a good idea. The following code will fill a temporary array and use it to replace your array in main thread.

```
NSMutableArray *tempAlbumArray = [NSMutableArray array];
//fill your array
[tempAlbumArray addObject:<#some object#>];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //replace your array with the new one
    //this code will be executed in main thread
    self.albumNameArray = tempAlbumArray;
});
```

Comment: As of now the app is running fine, hope this will fix the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `ARC` then Remove `[testArray release];` this line from your code because *`ARC` handle it*. Otherwise `[testArray release];` write in `-(void)dealloc` method.

Give condition before remove Array Value

```
if(myArray.count > 0)// because sometime it is good logic for us.
  [myArray removeAllObjects];
```

And then insert data in `myArray`.

Comment: I tried this also and still I got crash. And I tried to NSLog the count of the array after and before releasing an array, I got the same count and it was not zero. So, the count will be same even after we release an array??

Comment: I have added exception break points, so the error happened at [self.myArray removeAllObjects]; And also I used try and catch, so in the exception part the exception was NSRangeException.

Comment: @Mithuzz- if u put whole error message then i will help you without error message how can i help you ?? :) so plz put it :)

Comment: I understand why you are asking for error message but i got the error message only once today, and in the console i haven't got any error message only that NSRangeException message. And its very hard to recreate the issue.

Comment: Enable NSZombiesEnabled in your scheme, and see if your app catches anything.  This will cause your app to keep objects longer in memory to see if deallocated instances are accessed.  If you NSLog an array after it has been released from memory, it will not have a count as it won't exist.  Lose the [array release] calls, they are not needed in ARC when dealing with objective-c objects and will complicate matters.

Comment: I already enabled that and still I haven't got any log. And also I will try to log the array as you said. And also in the sample I mentioned, when i tried to log the count after release the array, I got the correct count.